# Email media query definitions required

Tags: html, css, media-queries, responsive

It's been a while since I had to do a responsive edm template and screen sizes have gotten larger.

I've been testing and failing miserably all afternoon - I essentially just wanted to have 2 media queries to target the 2 main breakpoints of:

1. Breakpoint 1 (iPhone 5S): 320px (shows 320px)
2. Breakpoint 2 (iPhone 6+): 414px (shows 375px)

So I don't understand why the below doesn't work

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 414px) {
  table.bannerTable img {width:375px !important;} 
}
@media screen and (max-width: 361px) {
  table.bannerTable img {width:320px !important;} 
}
```

I just want to have one banner image thats 700px wide in desktop, 375px wide in large smart phones and 320px wide in the rest of devices.

Comment: In what way does it not work? Where does `361` come from?

Comment: Good question - i just got that figure from various guides i read. even if i use  max-width: 320px - the 414 media query still shows on iPhone 6 for me. I basically just want iphone 6 plus and iphone7 plus to use the 414 (375px image width) and everything else to use 320px.... can't be that hard right?

Comment: Your issue resolved or still you have ?

Comment: You can use `img{max-width:100%;}`